# Is it expensive to compute vector size in for loops, each iteration?

Tags: c++, c++11

Does the c++ compiler take care of cases like, buildings is vector:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buildings.size(); i++) {}
```

that is, does it notice if buildings is modified in the loop or not, and then
based on that not evaluate it each iteration? Or maybe I should do this myself,
not that pretty but:

```
int n = buildings.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {}
```

Comment: This is such a tiny overhead (if any) that it is completely not worth worrying about.

Comment: *"not that pretty but"* - Well, `for (int i = 0, n = buildings.size(); i < n; i++) {}` is probably a bit prettier (more streamlined). But ok, the prettiest is probably `for (auto iter=buildings.begin(),end=buildings.end(); iter!=end; ++iter) {}` or even `for (auto&& building : buildings) {}`.

Comment: Or `for(int i = buildings.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: @Izkata Meh, that would require you to never ever use an unsigned type for `i`, which is a bit unintuitive given that `buildings.size()` is of unsigned integer type. Probably the good old *"downto-operator"* is a bit more streamlined: `for(auto i = buildings.size(); i --> 0;)`. But other than that, that completely changes the nature of iteration from forward to backward, which might not be acceptable in all cases (but is an option, and a nice micro-optimization in the best sense of the word, given that comparing to `0` could be an atom of a nanosecond faster than comparing to a variable).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`buildings.size()` will likely be inlined by the compiler to directly access the private size field on the `vector<T>` class. So you shouldn't separate the call to `size`. This kind of micro-optimization is something you don't want to worry about anyway (unless you're in some really tight loop identified as a bottleneck by profiling).

Comment: In many implementations, `size()` actually has to subtract two pointer members.  Which is still extremely cheap.

Comment: @aschepler Good point. - This is why I said "*likely ... access the private field*." :)

Comment: isnt that technically fieldS ?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl If I had to guess the internal implementation of `std::vector<T>`, I'd guess it has a `T* data`, a `std::size_t size`, and maybe a `std::size_t capacity`. The `size()` function would just return the private `size` field, which makes it easily inline-ready. - That's all I was trying to allude to. - An alternative implementation is no doubt possible, but I think this got the idea across. :)

Answer (score 8):

Don't decide whether to go for one or the other by thinking in terms of performance; your compiler may or may not inline the call - and `std::vector::size()` has constant complexity, too.

What you should really consider is correctness, because the two versions will behave very differently if you add or remove elements while iterating.

If you don't modify the vector in any way in the loop, stick with the former version to avoid a little bit of state (the `n` variable).

Comment: So you suggest I go for the first simple option, no matter if I modify the vector size or not?

Comment: I take that back:  Table 65:  "Those entries marked ‘‘(Note A)’’ should have constant complexity."  `size()` is marked "Note A"  However, "should" is a little wobbly here.

Comment: @user2381422: You would use the second version if you were appending elements to the vector as you iterate, but you only want to iterate up to the original end of the vector.

Comment: "should" in standard lingo means mandatory requirement. (but it does not state how big the constant time is :)

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler can determine that `buildings` isn't mutated within the loop (for example if it's a simple loop with no function calls that could have side effects) it will probably optmize the computation away. But computing the size of a vector is a single subtraction anyway which should be pretty cheap as well.

Write the code in the obvious way (`size` inside the loop) and only if profiling shows you that it's too slow should you consider an alternative mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I write loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0, maxI = buildings.size(); i < maxI; ++i)
```

Takes care of many issues at once: suggest max is fixed up front, no more thinking about lost performance, consolidate types. If evaluation is in the middle expression it suggests the loop changes the collection size.

Too bad language does not allow sensible use of const, else it would be const maxI.

OTOH for more and more cases I rather use some algo, lambda even allows to make it look almost like traditional code.

Comment: Perhaps `std::size_t` would be a better default than `int` for an index.

Comment: @GManNickG: `size_t` would certainly be better; if you wanted to be really pedantic about it, you'd use `std::vector<T>::size_type` since that's the type which `size()` returns.

Comment: I'm with the "default to int" camp, where I know from design that range of int is okay, I use int. But feel free to use the same thing with size_t. In the other regular use it is `auto` and inited with `.cbegin()` or `begin()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `size()` function is an inline function for the base-template, one can also assume that it's very little overhead. It is far different from, say, `strlen()` in C, which can have major overhead.

It is possible that it's still faster to use `int n = buildings.size();` - because the compiler can see that `n` is not changing inside the loop, so load it into a register and not indirectly fetch the vector size. But it's very marginal, and only really tight, highly optimized loops would need this treatment (and only after analyzing and finding that it's a benefit), since it's not ALWAYS that things work as well as you expect in that sort of regard.

Answer (score 0):

Only start to manually optimize stuff like that, if it's really a performance problem. Then measure the difference. Otherwise you'll lot's of unmaintainable ugly code that's harder to debug and less productive to work with. Most leading compilers will probably optimize it away, if the size doesn't change within the loop.

But even if it's not optimized away, then it will probably be inlined (since templates are inlined by default) and cost almost nothing.