# Const and non-const in one variable definition list in C++

Tags: c++, variables, standards, definition

Why it is not possible to define **const** and **non-const** variables in one definition list?

For example, in using `for` loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0, const iCount = data.size(); i < iCount; ++i);
```

It would be better from const-correctness viewpoint I guess.

P.S. I've asked this question wrong at first time. It is more for language designers rather than **"why it can be compiled on my machine?"**. I wanted to say that this would be much better if it would be implemented as syntax sugar in next C++ standards. Also this will prevent calls of `data.size()` in each loop iteration. I mean, why not to extent current C++ variable definition list to support `const` and `non-const` in single definition list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to declare two variables of different types in a for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: It isn't the `const` that is the problem (necessarily) it is the two different types.

Comment: @w.b Well I did not say it is. The only thing I wanted to say is "Okay, it is different types, but why it can be a sugar syntax, in new standard, for example"?

Comment: Your question was "why it is not possible..." and my answer was "it is illegal C++ syntax". Why the C++ standard committee decided to do this is another conversation entirely.

Comment: @Cyber, the C++ committee didn't decide it, the declarator grammar comes from C.

Comment: Yes, I've asked it wrong. But when I realized that a lot of people have already answered so I did not edit the question because of being late.

Comment: @Cyber: The problem *is* the `const` since, unlike some other modifiers, the declaration syntax doesn't allow you to add that to an individual declarator. Two different types aren't necessarily forbidden: `int i = 0, *p = &i;` is a perfectly cromulent declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to say that this would be much better if it would be implemented as syntax sugar in next C++ standards.

"Syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semi-colon."

Adding a "simple" change like that has a huge cost, in terms of complexity of the specification, complexity of compiler implementations, complexity of IDEs and code analysis tools, and doesn't necessarily make the language any easier to teach or use, except in the *one* specific case you've shown.

> Also this will prevent calls of data.size() in each loop iteration.

Have you checked whether there really are multiple calls in optimized code? If there aren't, why do we need a language extension to prevent something that doesn't happen?

> I mean, why not to extent current C++ variable definition list to support const and non-const in single definition list?

It wouldn't be widely useful anywhere except a `for` loop, and you can do it easily anyway:

```
{
  const size_t iCount = data.size();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < iCount; ++i)
    ;
}
```

Comment: I agree with anything but in last code snippet the `iCount` variable has 2 minor bad things in my opinion: at first it's scope is not only `for` loop but entire outer scope and second is that it needs one useless line of code.

Comment: The extra braces are there to make the scope identical. Sometimes trying to squeeze everything onto one line doesn't help clarity, especially if you have multiple declarations, and even more so when they have different types. So it's debatable if that extra line is useless, or actually makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Well, I did not pay attention to the extra braces in the snippet :) But, if we usually use `for` loop with one definition of "start" variable like `i` in the snippet I'd expect also to see `end` variable definition near it. Maybe it's just me but I see some use here. Also it will not require 2 extra braces :) Okay, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't since you can only have one type in the `for` loop declaration. `const` is part of the type.

Comment: It's a valid question though, as you can do e.g. `for (int i = 0, *j = &i; ...)` and `i` and `j` have different types.

Comment: But `*j` is the same type as `i`: `j` is a *pointer* to an `int` type. Indeed, it is a good question, which is why I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is simply a convention. It could be adopted that qualifiers might be included in declarators.

At present you may use cv-qualifiers with pointer declarators. For example such  construction is valid

```
int x, * const p = &x;
```

So I do not see serious reasons why this construction

```
int x, const y = 10;
```

could not be allowed.

You should ask this question at isocpp.org where the C++ Standard is discussed.:)

Comment: Thanks, that was the type of question I expected to see.

Comment: The reason why this one works is because the type of _p_ is `const pointer to int`, not  `pointer to const int`. Thus `*p` still has type `int`, thus it passes compilation.

Comment: @haavee But the declaration doesn't declare something with a mysterious name `*p`, it declares something with the name `p`. And the type of `p` is different from that of `x`.

Comment: According to the standard they are not. If you read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations carefully it sais that `*` (pointer-to) is not part of the _decl-specifier-seq_. It is a tough read that document but it's all there.

Comment: @haavee Yes, `*` is not part of the *decl-specifier-seq*, but the type is controlled by more than the *decl-specifier-seq*. `x` and `p` still have different type. `std::is_same<decltype(x), decltype(p)>::value` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `for` you can declare multiple variables provided they have the same type. `size_t` and `const size_t` are different types.

You don't need to declare `iCount` there, just write `; i < data.size();` as the condition.

Comment: Then it will perform `data.size()` call in each iteration. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Probably not if compiled with optimizations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945294/is-it-expensive-to-compute-vector-size-in-for-loops-each-iteration

Comment: @VictorPolevoy probably not, and even if it did, would it matter?

Comment: I think excess calls always matter. In this case - maybe not but think in optimizations. Of course we can move this calculations and assignments before the loop in this case but I am asking here about simplicity. Like in python. Also it will cost a few lines of code :) My question is about "why **not** to implement this? I think it would be useful".

Comment: @VictorPolevoy nope, they only matter when they actually effect performance. In my experience, 99% of the time you're better off writing readable code, rather than worrying about an extra call which is likely optimized away anyway. As to the "why", that's a question for the language designers.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are different data types and thus it's not a single definition list.

Comment: But `size_t i, *j;` declares two variables of different types.

Comment: It's the _cv_-qualifier ('const/volatile) that makes it different. One can read `*j` as "j is a variable that, when de-referenced, yields a type of size_t".

Comment: Yep, and so `i` and `j` are variables of different types.

Comment: You can also do `for (int i=0, j[2] = {0, 1};` where `i` and `j` again have different types.

Comment: Quoth http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations: _Each init-declaractor in an init-declarator sequence S D1, D2, D3; is processed as if it were a standalone declaration with the same specifiers: S D1; S D2; S D3;._

Comment: Right, so the rule is not that you can't have different data types, since the init-declarators D1 and D2 can produce different types.

Comment: That's not how I read this; as far as I understand it means that all _D1 ... Dn_ must evaluate to the same Lvalue type _S_. E.g. a specific _Dm_ could also declare a function which returns `size_t`.